# A bound on $\mathbb{E}[\max_{i} e^{pX_i}]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent, nonnegative random variables satisfying
$\mathbb{P}(X_i > t) \le a e^{-bt^2}$ for some constants $a, b >0$.

Can one show that for each $p>0$ there exist $A, B > 0$ such that
$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[\max_{1 \le i \le n} e^{pX_i}] \le A e^{B\sqrt{\log n}}$?